# ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>

Tags: python, pandas, argparse

Im new in python, need help in my code, please. I am trying to append data from multiple excel files to one file. But something goes wrong...

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="extract data from machine")

parser.add_argument("-d","--data", dest="data", required =True, action = "store", type=argparse.FileType("r", encoding="latin-1"), nargs="+",
                     help="the excel file you want to analysis")
parser.add_argument("-o","--outFileNamePrefix",action="store",default="foo",dest="out",
                    help="the output file name")
args = parser.parse_args()

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Target','Sample','SQ Mean', 'SQ Std. Dev'])
output.to_excel("%s_%s.xlsx"%(args.out), index=False)
filenames = args.data
for filename in filenames:
    for line in filename:
        data = pd.read_excel(args.data)
        data = data.to_excel(os.path.join("%s_%s.xlsx"%(args.out)))
```

I have this error

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful, please!

Comment: don't use `FileType` for the `data` argument.  It should a simple string, a filename, not an opened file.

Comment: Why those two loops? `for file in args.data: data=pd.read_excel(file)` would make more sense, after having made that argument a string as @hpaulj suggests.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your advises! Now it works!!!

Here is the final working code to merge multiple excel files with some data to one file using command line arguments.

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse

# parse command line args
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Extract data from machine")
parser.add_argument("-d","--data", dest="data", action = "store", nargs="+",
                     help="the excel file you want to analysis")
parser.add_argument("-o","--outFileNamePrefix",action="store",default="foo",dest="out",
                    help="the output file name")
args = parser.parse_args()

"""input data"""
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in args.data:
    data = pd.read_excel(file)
    df = df.append(data)
data_final = df.to_excel("%s_%s.xlsx"%(args.out), index=False)
```

First I made `args.data` a `string`, as @hpaulj suggestes I removed the `--data` `FileType`, so to make it simple string. Then, thanks to @joanis, made one loop `for file in args.data:` and `append` data to empty dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

`args.data` seems to be a `List` so perhaps try `args.data[0]`?